# Accessing a method of self inside a thread in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I want to propagate the `self` struct object into a thread and then call its `time_tick()` method for increasing the HMS time.

```rust
pub fn start(&mut self) {
    self.acti = true;   // the time tick is activated now...
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let local_self: *mut Self = self;   // this self live in the thread
        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));  // wait for 1 sec
            if (*local_self).acti == true { (*local_self).time_tick(); }    
            (*local_self).print_time();  // for debug
        }
    });
}
```

I get the error message:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/hmstimer/mod.rs:42:17
   |
42 |           thread::spawn(move || {
   |  _______________________^
43 | |             let local_self: *mut Self = self;   // this self live in the thread
44 | |             loop {
45 | |                 thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));    // wait for 1 sec
...  |
48 | |             }
49 | |         });
   | |_________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 40:2...
  --> src/hmstimer/mod.rs:40:2
   |
40 |       pub fn start(&mut self) {
   |  _____^
41 | |         self.acti = true;    // the time tick is activated now...
42 | |         thread::spawn(move || {
43 | |             let local_self: *mut Self = self;   // this self live in the thread
...  |
49 | |         });
50 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &mut hmstimer::HMSTimer
              found &mut hmstimer::HMSTimer
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/hmstimer/mod.rs:42:17: 49:7 self:&mut hmstimer::HMSTimer]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

But it seems that the about method is inappropriate. What is the best practice for doing the task?

Comment: You are trying to start a never ending thread that uses `self` every second. What do you expect it to do when `self` gets destroyed? There is a perfectly good reason why Rust is forbidding this.

Comment: How about using a `local_self` inside the thread? but my define seems not correct...

Comment: The type of`self` is `&mut Self`, so the type of `&mut self` is `&mut &mut Self`. The error message should make this obvious, so please always include it in your question. Fixing the problem with the type won't fix the lifetime issue @mcarton mentioned, though.

Comment: `if (*local_self).acti == true` — this is doubly redundant. Just use `if local_self.acti`. Likewise for `local_self.time_tick()` and `local_self.print_time()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass a closure that captures a mutable reference to [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html). `thread::spawn` needs the function to be `'static`, which means that either it captures no borrows, or that all borrows are `'static`. That's because the thread can continue running after the referent has been dropped.

If you don't need to use `self` in the original thread after calling `start`, then you can just pass `self` by value.

```
pub fn start(self) {
    self.acti = true;
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
            if self.acti == true { self.time_tick(); }    
            self.print_time();
        }
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) to get the two threads to share ownership of `Self`, as well as [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) to synchronize reads and writes across threads.

```
// note: this is not a method anymore;
// invoke as `HMSTimer::start(arc.clone());`
pub fn start(this: Arc<Mutex<Self>>) {
    this.lock().expect("mutex is poisoned").acti = true;
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
            let lock = this.lock().expect("mutex is poisoned");
            if lock.acti == true { lock.time_tick(); }    
            lock.print_time();
            // `lock` is dropped here, unlocking the mutex
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I got the following error when trying to lock `this` in the thread closure:
`\`(dyn for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r str) + 'static)\` cannot be sent between threads safely`