# How to do an "fire and forget" call in rust?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust

What I would like to achieve using the Rust language is to execute a closure or method after X seconds (without waiting for it). Being more used to languages like C#, a simple solution would be to spawn a thread, sleep for X seconds, and execute whatever needs to be done.

I tried this:

```rust
fn fire_and_forget(&self) {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
        self.do_something();
    });
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Depending on my context, I get errors like `error[E0277]: cannot be sent between threads safely` or `error[E0759]: self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it needs to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement`.

I hope there is solution for this. This "context" I am referring to is quite specific: this `fire_and_forget` method will be called from the outside so I am not sure I can change its signature with generic lifetimes.

Any idea if there is a solution / workaround / unsafe way for this?

Comment: Could you provide a specific example? It would also help to understand the context (command-line binary? WebAssembly?) and whether you already have an async runtime (e.g. `tokio`, `async-std`, etc.)

Comment: Yes! I am writing a dotnet (C#) profiler. That can should be done by implementing a COM interface in a native language (usually people do it in C++ but I chose Rust). I would like the profiler to detach 10 seconds after being attached. To do so, I need to call a COM function 10 seconds after the "attached" callback. There is no async context involved, at least for now.

Comment: I want a fire and forget mecanism because I don't want to sleep for 10 seconds inside the "attached" callback, since It might be fired from a thread shared from the application that is being profiled

Comment: Depending on what the code, you can take `&'static self`. Or wrap it in an `Arc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a method of self inside a thread in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971024/accessing-a-method-of-self-inside-a-thread-in-rust)

Comment: `'static` wasn't a possibility in my case but `Arc` might have been one ways to go, at the cost of complexifying things. It turns out my case is a bit specific because I found out that one the issues was a raw pointer field, which is non `Send` by default in rust and have to be implemented explicitly (unsafe)

Answer (score 2):

If you check out `thread::spawn`'s signature, you'll see that the closure is required to have a `'static` lifetime. This means that it must own all of its data and can not borrow from its environment. This rule exists because there is nothing that guarantees that the parent thread will outlive the newly spawned thread and thus there's no guarantee that any references inside the `thread::spawn` closure stay valid.

There are a few work-arounds here, although they depend on the structure of `self` and your program logic. They all boil down to getting owned data in the end and moving that owned data into the closure.

Let's assume you want to capture `self`'s state at the time of calling `fire_and_forget` and `Self: Clone`. In that case you can write the following:

```rust
let slf = self.clone(); // obtain an owned version of `slf`
thread::spawn(move || { // `move` makes the closure take ownership of `slf`
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
    slf.do_something() // borrows data from the closure, not the environment
})
```

If `Self` doesn't implement `Clone` or it's not okay to use the old state, you'll need some kind of synchronization / shared access to its current state, e.g. achievable through `Arc<Mutex<State>>`. Then you'll have to clone the `Arc`, move it into the closure and call `do_something` with the shared reference to `State`.

```rust
struct State {
    
}
struct Foo {
    state: Arc<Mutex<State>>,
}
impl Foo {
    fn do_something(state: &State) {

    }

    fn fire_and_forget(&self) {
        let owned_state = Arc::clone(&self.state); // obtain an owned version of `state`
        thread::spawn(move || { // `move` makes the closure take ownership of `state`
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
            let state = owned_state.lock().unwrap(); // get exclusive access to state
            Self::do_something(&*state) // borrows data from the closure, not the environment
        });
    
    }
}
```

Ultimately the solution will depend on your specific requirements, but as a general rule, a closure can't be `'static` if it borrows from its environment.

Comment: Copying the self did help but there was one more issue that I just found out!   
What happens in my case is that `Self` has a field with a raw pointer inside (required for COM). I just found out in the official documentation that *"Send and Sync are also automatically derived traits [...] with the major exception of raw pointers (because they have no safety guards) [...]"*    
So I just added `unsafe impl Send for StructWithRawPointerField {}` and it now compiles 