# Accessing non-dying self from inside thread closure created in that method

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing, closures

Basically this is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54971024/595305). But I'm trying to work out a more appropriate solution for my case.

Here is an MRE. The only dependency is `thread-pool = "*"`

```
use thread_pool::*;

fn main() {
    let framework = HandlingFramework{
        name: "Handler".to_string(),
    };
    framework.do_parallel_things()
}

struct HandlingFramework {
    name: String,
}

impl HandlingFramework {
    fn do_parallel_things(&self) {
        let n_virtual_cores = std::thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
        let (thread_sender, threadpool) = ThreadPool::fixed_size(n_virtual_cores);
        for n in 1..10 {
            println!("iteration {n}");
            let _ = thread_sender.send(move || {
                // inside this thread closure I want to create a useful structure
                // each time which is able to reference properties of the
                // handling framework
                println!("self.name {}", self.name)
                // println!("some alternative message making the program runnable")
            });
        }
        threadpool.shutdown();
        threadpool.await_termination();
    }
}
```

This gives that compile error as described, i.e.

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src\main.rs:21:15
   |
15 |       fn do_parallel_things(&self) {
   |                             -----
   |                             |
   |                             `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                             let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
21 |               let _ = thread_sender.send(move || {
   |  _____________________^
22 | |                 // inside this thread closure I want to create a structure each time which is able to reference properties of the
23 | |                 // handling framework
24 | |                 println!("self.name {}", self.name)
25 | |             });
   | |              ^
   | |              |
   | |______________`self` escapes the method body here
   |                argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

But... what I can see, and no doubt you can see, is something the compiler can't: that because the threadpool waits for termination of all the spawned threads before the method ends, in fact `self`'s lifetime in practice will never be an issue.

`&self` is also an immutable reference. So I can see that in fact referencing useful values of the framework inside these closures is never going to be a problem.

I've been trying to work out what the simplest solution to this might be, hopefully avoiding use of `Arc<Mutex<...`, but not necessarily*. Mightn't it be possible to get around this by using specific lifetime settings for one or more variables? At my level of Rust newbism I'm struggling with lifetimes.

Failing that, what about using `unsafe`? That would feel like a failure. And also doesn't `unsafe` remove ALL compiler protections, not just the one which you need to remove?

---

* I'm not entirely sure how to implement that in fact. But I suspect, as I say, that it's too much engineering for a case like this. I may well be wrong.

Comment: Just use a [`scoped-thread-pool`](https://crates.io/crates/scoped-thread-pool) instead of a plain `thread-pool`.

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751956/5397009

Comment: @Jmb Thanks. I just tried scoped-thread-pool, replacing `send` with `threadpool.spawn`. This led to the same error. Any chance you might show how a scoped threadpool solution might work?

Comment: `spawn()` is for the `'static` case. You need to use [`scoped()`](https://docs.rs/scoped-thread-pool/latest/scoped_thread_pool/struct.Pool.html#method.scoped) and [`execute()`](https://docs.rs/scoped-thread-pool/latest/scoped_thread_pool/struct.Scope.html#method.execute) on it.

Comment: Oh wow, got it (scoped solution). Fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Jmb and ChayimFriedman.

```
use scoped_thread_pool::*;

fn main() {
    let framework = HandlingFramework{
        name: "Handler".to_string(),
    };
    framework.do_parallel_things()
}

struct HandlingFramework {
    name: String,
}
    
impl HandlingFramework {
    fn do_parallel_things(&self) {
        let n_virtual_cores = std::thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
        let threadpool = Pool::new(n_virtual_cores);
        let _ = threadpool.scoped(|scope| {
            for n in 1..10 {
                println!("iteration {n}");
                scope.execute(move ||{
                    println!("self.name {} iteration {n}", self.name)
                })
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This "scoped" stuff is some kind of deep magic. Will investigate what's going on.

And in fact it works even without `threadpool.shutdown()`. From the docs: "`scoped` will return only when the scheduler function and all jobs queued on the given `Scope` have been run".

Comment: You need to put the `for n in 1..10` loop inside the `scoped` closure, because the thread pool waits for the thread to finish before returning from `scoped`, so your current code only runs a single thread at a time!

Comment: Useful to know! Edited.